# GetExitCodeProcess() throws first chance exception with Application Verifier

Tags: c++, winapi, application-verifier

I use CreateProcess() to run an executable and call GetExitCodeProcess() at the end to get the exit code of the process. When I run it with application verifier I get a first chance exception. I've attached a picture of the log.[image]

Line number 1348 is line immediately after GetExitCodeProcess() call. I'm not very familiar with the log format so I'm asking is the exception thrown inside GetExitCodeProcess() in which case can I ignore it or am I doing something wrong in my code because it's pointing to the line after the call to GetExitCodeProcess()?

Edit: my code:

```
  if (!CreateProcess(
    NULL,  // it will get the app name from the next argument
    cString, // command line
    NULL,
    NULL,
    TRUE, // don't inherit handles
    CREATE_NO_WINDOW,
    NULL, // use environment of the calling process
    NULL, // use same current drive and directory as the calling process
    &siStartupInfo,
    &processInfo
    ))
  {
    // If process failed return error
    ...
  }

  // Close handles the passed to the child process.
  CloseHandle(hChildStd_ERR_Wr);
  CloseHandle(hChildStd_OUT_Wr);

  // Now read the std::out and std::err from child process and store them in strings to return
  DWORD dwRead;
  CHAR chBuf[4096];
  memset(chBuf, 0, 4096);
  BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
  UString out = "", err = "";
  for (;;) {
    bSuccess=ReadFile( hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, 4096, &dwRead, NULL);
    if( ! bSuccess || dwRead == 0 )
      break;

    UString s(chBuf, dwRead);
    out += s;
  }
  dwRead = 0;
  memset(chBuf, 0, 4096);
  for (;;) {
    bSuccess=ReadFile( hChildStd_ERR_Rd, chBuf, 4096, &dwRead, NULL);
    if( ! bSuccess || dwRead == 0 )
      break;

    UString s(chBuf, dwRead);
    err.append(s);
  }

  consoleOutput = out;
  errorOutput = err;

  // Wait for the process to finish. Wait shouldn't happen before reading from pipes because
  // pipe writes happen only when someone is reading from them. For small amounts of data
  // this would not be a problem because the Pipe Manager buffer will consume data so the
  // write will succeed. But for large amounts of data, a reader must be present if not
  // the writer will wait indefinitely.
  WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess,INFINITE);

  // Close handles returned from Child process
  CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
  CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);

  // Close read handles of the pipe
  CloseHandle(hChildStd_ERR_Rd);
  CloseHandle(hChildStd_OUT_Rd);

  // Get exit code for the process
  DWORD exitStat = 0;
  GetExitCodeProcess(processInfo.hProcess,&exitStat);
```

Comment: It would be useful to see your actual code.  Is the process handle still valid?  Did you maybe close it?

Comment: I've added my code to the question. I actually do close the handle before calling GerExitCodeProcess(). Is that an issue? I thought the data would still be retained in the handle object.

Comment: Yes, that is an issue. You are passing an invalid handle to `GetExitCodeProcess()`. You closed the handle, it is no longer valid, the process does not exist anymore, the data is gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `GetExitCodeProcess()` **after** you have already closed the `hProcess` handle, so you are passing an invalid handle to it, and that is exactly what the verifier's error log is telling you:

> **Invalid handle exception** for current stack trace

You need to leave `hProcess` open until after you are completely done using it, which includes passing it to `GetExitCodeProcess()`.

Comment: As a side question, any idea why Application Verifier pointed to the line immediately after the `GerExitCodeProcess()` call and not the actual call?

Comment: @Dula because the CPU records return addresses, not caller addresses.

Comment: I am trying to understand a similar issue, in my case i am deliberately passing a NULL handle to `GetExitCodeProcess()` so application verifier catches it (and it does) but if I choose to continue after the breakpoint then an exception is thrown at an address which I cann't map to anything! Why is this exception thrown after it caught the NULL handle? Why the address doesn't correspond to any register or anything else? Even break point doesn't work on that address.